# Setting up an HTTP endpoint for Azure EventGrid Webhook in my MVS Webapp?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to create an Azure Eventgrid and Webhook response to send me inbound text messages from Azure communications services to my Azure hosted WebApp. Right now I'm having a really hard time finding documentation that shows how to create an endpoint within a Webapp controller to get the Azure webhook response to handshake and validate. I've created an endpoint within my controller that I believe should be catching the the data and processing it in a POST method, but it fails because of the arguments I'm trying to mimic. Any insight on this topic is appreciated.

I tried integrating a lot of what I found in these Docs into my app controller to try and get it to work, but I think I might be doing this all the wrong way since it says this code is for an Azure function??? I'm not entirely sure how those are used, but I tried integrating the same C# code into my controller. See Docs below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events

And here is the controller I have that is trying to imitate what I read in the docs I linked

```
        [HttpPost("incoming")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFlightInfo([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest incoming,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        string response = string.Empty;
        BinaryData events = await BinaryData.FromStreamAsync(incoming.Body);
        log.LogInformation($"Received events: {events}");

        EventGridEvent[] egEvents = EventGridEvent.ParseMany(events);

        foreach (EventGridEvent eventGridEvent in egEvents)
        {
            // Handle system events
            if (eventGridEvent.TryGetSystemEventData(out object eventData))
            {
                // Handle the subscription validation event
                if (eventData is SubscriptionValidationEventData subscriptionValidationEventData)
                {
                    log.LogInformation($"Got SubscriptionValidation event data, validation code: {subscriptionValidationEventData.ValidationCode}, topic: {eventGridEvent.Topic}");
                    // Do any additional validation (as required) and then return back the below response

                    var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponse()
                    {
                        ValidationResponse = subscriptionValidationEventData.ValidationCode
                    };
                    return new OkObjectResult(responseData);
                }
            }
        }
                return new OkObjectResult(response);
    }
```

Comment: you should consider using the *Azure SignalR Service* for your solution, see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110732/subscribing-to-an-azure-event-grid-topic-directly-from-an-angular-client

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to start by deploying and exploring the Azure Event Grid Viewer sample application according to the [`Handle SMS events for Delivery Reports and Inbound Messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/handle-sms-events) tutorial.
This app is designed to consume any events generated by the Event Grid, including the SMS ones. The app utilizes SignalR, just as [@roman-kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8084828/roman-kiss) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57130996/1332034), to push the events in near real time to the user.

Once you get a good grasp of the whole flow, you can start adjusting the code to match your use case. A good first step would be adjusting the [deserialization logic](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-event-grid-viewer/blob/966243da967bc889b57c1f51a019d8ec09af0b9d/viewer/Controllers/UpdatesController.cs#L95-L115) to take advantage of more specific models. You can get the sample JSON models for SMS events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-telephony-sms-events) and convert them to [C#](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp).